# Using Express and Multer for file uploading: getting a file in random name and unknown format

Tags: node.js, express, multer

I'm new to web dev so sorry if this is sully question. I'm building a webapp that can upload a zip file along with some form data.

On the client side I'm using axios and here is a segment of the code:

```
  handleSubmitClick = (e) => {
    console.log(this)
    e.preventDefault();    

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('uploaded_file',this.state.file)
    formData.append('studyID',this.state.studyID)
    formData.append('modality',this.state.modality)
    const config = {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        }
    }
    return post('/test_post', formData, config)
  }
```

On the backend api side, I'm using Express with Multer middleware to receive the file:

```
import express from 'express';
import cors from 'cors';

var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var multer = require('multer');
var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' })
const path = require('path');

const initializeExpress = (): void => {
  const app = express();

  app.use(cors());
  app.use(express.json());
  // app.use(express.urlencoded());
  app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
  app.use(bodyParser.json());

  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));
  

  app.post('/test_post', upload.single('uploaded_file'), function (req, res){
    console.log('---------- post test_post ----------')
    console.log("req.body: ", req.body)
    console.log('--------------------------------')
    
    return res.send('pong');
  })
 
  app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
};

initializeExpress();
```

When select a zip file and click a "send" button on the webpage, I can see the following console log on the Express backend api side:

```
---------- post test_post ----------
req.body:  [Object: null prototype] {
  studyID: '123qwe',
  modality: 'CT'
}
--------------------------------
```

The form data `studyID` and `modality` are received correctly. Since these two form data are automatically extracted from the selected file, I can confirm that the file is selected with no problem. (`this.state.file` indeed points to the right file object)

However, the `uploaded_file` field is an empty string and there is a file `uploads/` folder:

```
- uploads
     3b3b93d6c2db52ff6d66d60d0315d7fc
```

The original file selected was `testfile.zip`, but this file has unknown format and a random name.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The original file selected was testfile.zip, but this file has unknown
> format and a random name.

What you need is to control the file's name and extension. You can do it using [storage option](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer#storage)

You can replace this line:

```
var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' });
```

by:

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, 'uploads/') // where files will be saved
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.originalname) // using the file's original name
  }
})
 
const upload = multer({ storage: storage })
```